# Unsupervised Neural Network with Independent hidden Activations: How to implement entropy or kurtosis penalty?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, unsupervised-learning, autoencoder

In brief:

How do I implement ICA-like entropy or kurtosis penalty term for the cost and back-propagation of my unsupervised neural network (I'm using stacked sparse Autoencoders)?

In details:

I've implemented sparse Autoencoder (AE) in Matlab based on Andrew Ng's UFLDL tutorials with conjugate gradient descent and Wolfe line search. This achieves much cleaner results on my data than Independent Component Analysis (ICA) with infomax (I compare my AE's hidden layer activations with the ICA activations of eeglab's runica function.)

However, maximal independence of the activations, as in ICA, is also an essential criterion to me. So I'd like to achieve the higher quality sNN hidden activations but making them also independent. In other words I'd like to benefit from both sparsity and independence.

ICA uses entropy or kurtosis penalty term to minimize mutual information across the components (activations).

I've tried simply to apply matlab's wentropy or kurtosis function: if a given hidden layer's activation matrix 'a' is (outputNeurons*hiddenNeurons), I'd do:

```
betaEntropy = 0.01;
for m = 1:size(a,1)
    entropyM(m) = abs(wentropy(a(m,:),'shannon'));
    % kurtosisM(m) = abs(kurtosis(a(m,:)));
end         
entropyPenalty = betaEntropy * mean(entropyM);
cost = cost + Wdecay + sparsityJ + entropyPenalty;
```

This gave bad results and no independent activations. I think I should also calculate the error of the penalty for the back-propagation but I wasn't sure how. I'm not sure my above cost penalty is correct either.

Any ideas either to improve the above code or just to point me to the right directions in simple mathematical terms?

Comment: you need to add the gradient of your entropy to the original gradient of cost function to propagate it through the network. This is "just" matrix differentiation.

Comment: thanks @lejlot but how would you calculate the gradient of entropy function? Numerically computing it at each iteration is too slow. I'm also not sure how could I get the gradient of other related terms that I could use, such as the gradient of covariance or kurtosis.